# How was the nature of rama in all phases of his life?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama

We mostly hear about notorious and very diverse nature of Shri Krishna, personally I have never herd about the nature of Shri Rama in his various phases of life and the amount of knowledge he posses (in case of krishna his wisdom is well propagated as Shrimad Bhagwad Gita). Krishna had a body made out of full sattva and because of that his body never aged beyond 25 years so he was like gods who do not age. What about lord Rama? People also talk about the Thunderous characteristic voice of Shriman Narayanas purna avatars did Rama had such voice and what is the reason of having such deep voice?

Comment: The nature of Rama in all phases of life is satya and dharma. If you are looking for physical characteristics, Hanuman describes Rama is vivid detail in the Sundara Kanda. As to the voice, one possible earthly explanation is that Rama had a fully open visuddha chakra.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I am talking about his eerie calm, and fully controlled nature as described by Shriman Narayana in Bhagwad Gita for a Sthirbuddhi. I think if human being just copies nature of Shrirama he can attain that State of Sthirbuddhi and becomes eligible for moksha. Again I don't believe in Chakra concept. I used the word 'eerie' because his calm nature was frightening for his foes, and it was strange even for his close acquaintances like Lakshmana and Dashratha.

Comment: "Krishna .. never aged beyond 25 years" - do you have a source for this claim?

Answer (score 2):

Valmiki and Narada talk about SriRama's 16 qualities in the very first shlokas of [Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga1/bala_1_frame.htm)

```
guna-vaan  
virya-vaan  
dharma-gnya  
kruta-gnya  
satya-vaakya  
drida-vrata  
chaaritrena-yukta  
sarvabhuteshu-hita  
vidvaan  
samartha  
eka-priya-darshana  
aatma-vaan  
jita-krodha  
dyuti-maan  
anasuyaka  
bibhyati-deva
```

During the many phases of his life, each of these qualities was shown in practice by Maryada Purushottam Ram. You may like to listen to Ramayana upanyasam from satvik gurus to learn when and where he displayed them.

Since both Rama & Krishna are just different avataras of the same MahaVishnu, their physical bodies are shudda-satva.

Answer (score 1):

In kamba Ramayanam, Kambar states that Lord Rama is always quiet, he do not get angry, soft spoken, never hate anybody, respect shown to parents, elders, rishis etc. Of course Lord Rama showed how a human should live by having these qualities. For that only he took that avatar.